# Wordpress Comments jQuery Doesn't submit

Tags: comments, jquery, comment-form

I am trying to check if the commentform is filled in after submition, and only submit it when it is filled in.

I am using:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Handle Checks
    $(this).submit();
});
```

But it's not submitting at all, any idea why this isn't working?
Works on regular contact form in wordpress btw.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess there is a typo, it should be `e.preventDefault()` and not e.preventDefault. Can you please check?

Comment: @MarutiMohanty Yes. My bad. I already have that in code though. And it's not returning any warnings/errors. (JS)

Comment: Can't answer. But the answer is: I found an other way around it. I solved it replacing:

    $('form').submit();

With:

    $('form').unbind('submit');
    $('#submit').click();

:)

Answer (score 0):

Original Poster's answer in comments also worked for me, will share it here so this can have a solution.

Replace:

```
 $('form').submit();
```

With:

```
 $('form').unbind('submit'); $('#submit').click();
```

I used this to submit comments with JQuery with the ENTER key rather than clicking the button:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#comment').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {//capture ENTER Key 
       $('form').unbind('submit'); $('#submit').click();
        return false;
       }
    });
});
```